# OpenGL ES 2.0 2D (Marmalade SDK)

Tags: textures, 2d, opengl-es-2.0, marmalade

Please look at [source code](http://pastebin.com/6LD3cb48) it looks like salad of beetroot but maybe one of you will find why it renders glitch textured quad. I spent a lot of time to find mistake without results. I try to render quad (two triangles), texture it and blend with vertex colors. As I understand mistake happens with texture coordinates.

**Update:**

[original picture](http://www.kevinbeason.com/smallpt/result_25k.png) of texture;

[screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/uynja4psn/) for `gl_FragColor = vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5 );`

[screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/9i3ud6wjl/) for `gl_FragColor = texColor;`

[screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/ohh19oug3/) for `gl_FragColor = vec4( v_texCoord.x, v_texCoord.y, 0.0, 0.5 );`

Comment: Do you have any OpenGL errors with this code?

Comment: Sergey, as I know there are no errors. In code you'll find a lot of lines like "GLint lastError =::eglGetError();" without using it. It is because I removed outputing value of lastError to stdout/file after each call;

Comment: Can you make a screenshot of what you see on a device?

Comment: If you change ``gl_FragColor = texColor * v_color;`` to ``gl_FragColor = vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5 );`` what do you see?

Comment: Sergey, I made update for your comments;)

Comment: This means your texture is wrong. Now, try ``gl_FragColor = vec4( v_texCoord.x, v_texCoord.y, 0.0, 0.5 );`` to see if UV coordinates are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When debugging OpenGL shaders by hand, there is a strategy to localize where the problem is.
We will use `gl_FragColor` to dump the results of various calculations within your shaders.

For example, we change your `gl_FragColor = texColor * v_color;` to `gl_FragColor = vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5 );` to see if the geometry is rendered correctly. If you see a fullscreen red quad, this means your vertex transformations are ok.

Move on, check your texture coordinates: `gl_FragColor = vec4( v_texCoord.x, v_texCoord.y, 0.0, 0.5 );` The result should be a gradual red/green color ramp.

The wrong color ramp means your UV texture coordinates are wrong. Indeed. You don't setup texture coordinates in `void Render(Context* context)`.

Comment: Updated. As I see gradient only in one triangle.

Comment: @Edward83: UV coordinates are wrong. Check if your ``void Render(Context* context)`` sets up the tex coordinates correctly.

Comment: Sergey, thank you for your time, patience and attention. Bounty is yours! СпасиБо!

Comment: @Edward83: Пожалуйста! :)